# GCM doesn't work when app is forced closed, why does facebook app still works?

Tags: google-cloud-messaging, forceclose

ok, I've been recently playing with GCM and it seems that when you force close your app, the GCM messages cannot be received anymore.

so the question is that how does FB app works? that even though I force close it, it still send the GCM notifications?!!! any idea?